# Efficiently query a large(~1M) records SQL table with Paging and .NET Caching(or not)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, caching

What would be an efficient way to query a large(~1M) SQL table with user records with paging and caching(or not) ?

This table is used by a asp.net website that its main purpose is to allow searching, filtering and sorting on this table based on several parameters (country , from/to year range, gender , etc..).

The results (a list of user id) are displayed in some grid (25 rows per page with paging)

The users table has updates/inserts a few times a minute and there are a lot of read requests for the table (searching and filtering).

**We can allow results displayed to be 10 minutes old.

**Currently we use the following method:**

Each (first) search request is passed to the SQL server and results (user IDs) are stored in .NET cache for a period of 10 minutes based on the filter parameters and paging page.

For example a search request for Country:

```
Spain| From:1980 | To:2020 | Gender: Male | Page:1 , We create two cache keys:

Main cache: Spain_1980_2020_Male (Based on filter parameters)

Secondary cache: Spain_1980_2020_Male_Page1 (based on filter parameters + page)
```

Next requests with the same search parameters & page will be returned directly from cache without hitting SQL.

After 10 minute the main cache key and all secondary page keys are cleared (using .NET on absolute cache expiration and cache dependency)

Any suggestions for a less complex or more efficient approach to search the table ?

Comment: Does your current code work? Is it fast enough?

Comment: I have a bug of random null reference which lead me to wanting to rewrite.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to optimise something that isn't working. I would focus instead on getting it working, **then** try and optimise it. Can you share us the details (including code) of some of these random (cough) null references?

Comment: Why are you caching? The query results seem too specific to be re-used?

Comment: @hintham The query results are specific but same parameters/page combination are requested many times during the 10 mins time-frame. caching reduces the response time dramatically.

Comment: @mjwills - query is working without cache but much slower

Comment: So the `random null references` - what were they referring to? Just when the cache is enabled? _If so, you need to show us your code that populates and reads from the cache._

Comment: @mjwills thanks but i'm looking for advise on alternative solutions rather then helping me find the bug.

Comment: `Any suggestions for a less complex or more efficient approach to search the table ?` Your description seems reasonably simple and efficient. _I can't suggest any simpler or more efficient options without seeing your current code._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the null exception by rewriting the following bit of code (posting as an answer although it wasn't the main purpose of this question):

Old code:

```
var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
if (cache[cacheKey] != null)
{
   users = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as List<int>;
}
else
{
 // load from DB
}
```

New code:

```
var users = cache[cacheKey] as List<int>;
if (user == null)
{
  //load from DB
}
```